# trying to generate an organization chart with the google Api but it doesn't seem to work. Like the Ajax code is not firing

Tags: .net, json, model-view-controller, razor, charts

I am trying to generate an organization chart with the google Api but it doesn't seem to work. Like the Ajax code is not firing. I am sure the controller gets the Data from the database because i saw it in the debug output. And im sure my javascript code is firing because i tried with some alert("").

OrgaController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DrawOrga()
    {
        List<Structure> StructList = new List<Structure>();

        string query = "SELECT code, name, depend FROM Structure";

        string connetionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-*******\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=****;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {

                        // Adding new Structure object to List
                        StructList.Add(new Structure()
                        {
                            Code = dr.GetInt32(0),
                            Name = dr.GetString(1),
                            Depend = dr.IsDBNull(2) ? 0 : dr.GetInt32(2)

                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }


        return Json(StructList);
    }

}
```

Structure.cs

```
namespace ANDA_FRONTEND.Models
{
    public class Structure
    {
        public Structure()
        {
        }

        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Depend { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is where the code should fire and generate the Chart. I have an Api Key

```
@model ANDA_FRONTEND.Models.Structure

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Organigramme";
}


<h1>TEST</h1>
<div id="chart">
</div>
<button id="btnLoadChart" class="btn" onclick="drawChart()">Click Me</button>
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=*************"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        $('#btnLoadChart').click(function () {
            drawChart();
        });

        function drawChart() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Orga", "DrawOrga")",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert("test2");
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Entity');
                    data.addColumn('string', 'ParentEntity');
                    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
                    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                        var Code = r[i][0].toString();
                        var Name = r[i][1];
                        var Depend = r[i][2] != null ? r[i][2].toString() : '';
                        data.addRows([[{
                            v: Code,
                            f: Name
                        }, Depend]]);
                    }
                    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart($("#chart")[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, `www.google.com/jsapi` should no longer be used, it is outdated.

the new version is --> `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`

this will **only** change the `load` statements.

from...

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

to...

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["orgchart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

check the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

---

next, you are adding three columns to the data table, here...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Entity');
data.addColumn('string', 'ParentEntity');
data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
```

but you are only adding values for two columns, here...

```
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
  var Code = r[i][0].toString();
  var Name = r[i][1];
  var Depend = r[i][2] != null ? r[i][2].toString() : '';
  data.addRows([[{
    v: Code,
    f: Name
  }, Depend]]);
}
```

you need to either remove the tooltip column,
or add a value for the column...

```
  data.addRows([[{
    v: Code,
    f: Name
  }, Depend, '']]);  // <-- blank tooltip column
```

Comment: hope this helps -- note: you can check the browser's console for errors (press F12)